# Papa Parse and large csv files

Tags: javascript, csv, large-files, papaparse

I have a 2 gig csv file to parse and I think node only allows memory usage below 1 gig and im getting this error:

`Attempt to allocate Buffer larger than maximum size: 0x3fffffff bytes.`

I would Like to stream the file and write it to a data.json file.

Then use mongoimport to write it to mongo. I'm open to any ideas if there's a more efficient way.
I have been using csvtojson but i would prefer to use papaparse as its the best parser ive seen and really enjoy using it.

Using csvtojson

```
function csvToJson(callback){

console.log("in csvToJson");

var csvConverter = new Converter({constructResult: false, delimiter: delimiter, noheader: false  });

var readStream = require("fs").createReadStream("fileName");

var writeStream = require("fs").createWriteStream("outputData.json");

writeStream.on("close", function () {
    callback();
    readStream.close();
    writeStream.close();
});

readStream.pipe(csvConverter).pipe(writeStream);
```

}

Comment: split the initial file, if you can.

Comment: I have tried splitting it using shell commnads:

`cp.execSync("split --bytes 500M --numeric-suffixes --suffix-length=3 C:\\fileFolder\\large.csv C:\\tempFoder\\NEW.", function(err, data){
        console.log(data);

    });`

It worked fine, but it adds a whole new step to the program, which takes even more time.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29767502/4088809

Comment: and this : http://www.codexpedia.com/javascript/increasing-the-memory-limit-in-node-js/