# How to parse JSON that is larger than 256mb?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm migrating my app's backend from Parse to Apple's CloudKit. I have a file `Datapoint.json` that is nearly a gigabyte (represents 2.5 million Parse objects). I'm trying to import this in my `migration.js` script but I keep getting the error `toString failed`.

I read up on this error and it seems that a file can't be bigger than 256mb. What should I do?

```
var json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./Datapoint.json', 'utf8'));
```

Comment: what operating system are you working with?

Comment: Use a streaming JSON parser. And don't try to  `readFileSync`.

Comment: OS X 10.11.4 my computer has a 3.1ghz i7 and 16gb of ram

Comment: What are you going to do with `json`?

Comment: Did you use google? http://www.ngdata.com/parsing-a-large-json-file-efficiently-and-easily/

Comment: I'm going to turn it into CloudKit records and save them slowly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766868/node-js-read-big-file-with-fs-readfilesync

Comment: First read file asynchronously then use JSON Parser.

Comment: @bilalmetla what's the advantage of readying it asynchronously? It's a one time operation

Comment: Use stream based solutions find out how the file is structured and use this stream library https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream.

Comment: Your file is too big. This will block event loop. Asynchronoulsy it will work fine.

Comment: @bilalmetla the JSON.parse is not async function so it will block the event loop, but if you split it into stream like I commented before it would be parse the chunks easily.

Comment: To be fair, on a 64-bit OS it really *should* be possible to work with an in-memory gigabyte file.

Comment: Yes you can use any external library for this.

Comment: @bilalmetla I'm still running out of memory with JSONStream

Comment: make sure you understand the inside structure how the rows/objects locate, .pipe(JSONStream.parse('results.*'))

Comment: Can you share exact error. May be your node process memeory exceeds.

Comment: The parse backup structure should be like this http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/one-click-export/, so you should be able to use this ```cat backup.json | JSONStream 'results.*'```